# Getting JQuery slider to stop on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have [a web site](http://townappliance.arosavd.com/) with a jQuery slider that automatically slides when the page is loaded. How can I get the slider to stop when the mouse hovers over it?

I'm using the following jQuery code:

```
  var my_jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);

  window.onload = function () {

        // added  by pesach

        var totalWidth=0;
        var numItems=0;
        my_jQuery('li', 'div#scroll_Bar').each (function() {

        totalWidth = totalWidth + my_jQuery(this).outerWidth() + 1;
        numItems = numItems + 1;

        });
        //alert(totalWidth * -1);

        my_jQuery('ul', 'div#scroll_Bar').width(totalWidth);
        var slidewidth = totalWidth - 960;
        //end of addition


        var container = $('div#scroll_Bar');
        var ul = $('ul', container);

        var itemsWidth = ul.innerWidth() - container.outerWidth();

        //$("div.sliderGallery ul li").hover(stop(true, true), stop(true, true));
        my_jQuery('ul', 'div#scroll_Bar').animate({'left' : slidewidth * -1}, numItems * 1000, 'linear');
        my_jQuery('ul', 'div#scroll_Bar').animate({'left' : 0}, numItems * 800, 'linear');


        my_jQuery('.slider', container).slider({
            min: 0,
            max: itemsWidth,
            handle: '.handle',
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                ul.animate({'left' : ui.value * -1}, 500),my_jQuery('ul', 'div#scroll_Bar').stop(true, true);
            },
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                ul.css('left', ui.value * -1),my_jQuery('ul', 'div#scroll_Bar').stop(true, true);
            }
        });

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly using the .stop() command?

So after your 2 animate lines:

```
my_jQuery('ul','#scoll_Bar').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop();
});
```

Also, there's no point in having `div` before elements with an ID, so remove them:
<strike>div</strike>#scroll_Bar

Comment: Thank you for your response. After putting in the code it still wont stop when i put the mouse over it. you can check out the link to see (i added the code). if you have any further suggestions it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance